# If I restore my electrum wallet from seed will I lose my pending transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, electrum, seed, wallet-recovery

So I have seen everywhere that boosting fees can be a scam and I do not have enough techy knowledge to do so anyhow or for that matter to directly delete my transaction using pythonwallet.

Whilst sending my transaction I noticed I could set the amount of fees on it and naively decided to set it to the minimum grinning at my own cunning and simultaneously frowning at why it would let me do that. 2 hours later when my transaction was unconfirmed I started to think something unusual might have happened and since (24hrs later) I have spent most of my time learning about bitcoin transactions, something I might have done beforehand...

Anyhow, now I am looking to stop my wallet rebroadcasting the transaction in the simplest way possible so that I can recover my money and send it again with a higher fee and having enabled the replace by fee option. Can someone quickly reassure me that if I restore my electrum wallet by seed it will stop the transaction and that my funds will come back to me and maybe give me some info on how long that will take. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your transaction is out in the network. It doesn't need to be rebroadcasted by your wallet (which probably doesn't do this anyways all by itself) in order to survive. It just needs to be in someone's mempool. Deleting your wallet will not stop the transaction. When you delete your wallet and restore it with your seed, you will have access to the same money you have access to now, but the notes you may or may not have stored in your Electrum wallet will be gone.